# Uploading CSV data to Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a CSV file with 1000 rows and about 15 columns. I was planning to store each row as a simple JSON object as the Redis value and the row number of the CSV file as the Redis key. However once I start uploading multiple CSV files to Redis, what's the best way to distinguish one CSV file from another in the DB? Isn't Redis just all key-values with no other larger structures than keys other than different Redis DB instances themselves? I know Redis is in memory but even so... isn't it a bit inefficient to go search for the desired key if you have millions of records? I don't get it. If I uploaded 1 million CSV files, and each had 1000 rows, that would be 1 billion records to search, which is too many even for an in-memory DB. I should do it another way.

I am looking for a way to represent each of my CSV files in Redis in an efficient and sensible manner, where each CSV file row has it's own unique key, and the Redis value will be the column headers and data.

How do I accomplish this?

One solution would be for each key to represent the entire CSV file, but I am looking to see if there is another option.

Comment: what's the best key for your data in redis is really depends on how you will be using your data and the characteristics of your data. You can start with using the unique id in your csv as key. This article http://openmymind.net/Data-Modeling-In-Redis/ will help you to have a general idea.

Answer (score 2):

You get creative.

You don't specify whether it's important to keep all of the CSVs separate, or if all of the data could be lumped into one "group"-ish type of logical structure (like you would in a table in an RDBMS).

Operating on the assumption that all of the data could go together, you could keep one key to increment a global counter for your IDs for each "row":

```
// synchronous for easy writing/reading
var rowid = client.get('csv row counter');
rowid = rowid || 1;

// `csv` is an array of your json objects
for (var i=0; i<csv.length; i++) {
    client.set('csv-'+(rowid+i), JSON.stringify(csv[i]));
}

client.set('csv row counter', rowid+i);
```

If you need to use this method, just make sure that `rowid` is scoped correctly so that simultaneous uploads will increment appropriately.

If, instead, you need to keep track of each CSV separately, then you just need to name the row with some reference to its CSV:

```
// `csvname` is initialized with the chosen name for this csv
for (var i=0; i<csv.length; i++) {
    client.set(csvname+'-'+i, JSON.stringify(csv[i]));
}
```

Comment: yes, you could put all the data for an entire CSV file into one key-value pair, I was just thinking that might not be very efficient, especially for search

Comment: I didn't remotely suggest you should put the entire CSV into one key-value pair, but rather that the keys for the rows of different CSV needn't be logically separate (in the first example).  If you need them to be logically separate, you can use the second example.

Answer (score 2):

Key-value stores let you replace a linear search for a row in a CSV file with a faster search (usually O(log n)) in a data structure. And may give you range queries over key values as well.

Using *only* the file name as a key doesn't buy you much over using leaving the data in the file system. But `{file name}.{row number}`, and storing each row as a value, might be what you need, depending on what is in each row.

In a nutshell: store small values; pick something you search for frequently, and that is meaningful when sorted, as the key.